# Material UI TableCell onclick not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Right now I'm trying to make so that when a cell in a table is clicked the console logs "hi".
Here is the code for a table cell.

```
<TableCell  onClick = {console.log("hi")} id = 'tc' padding = "checkbox" align = 'center' color = "primary" 
variant = 'contained' 
style = {{textAlign:'center',minWidth:'12vw',maxWidth:'12vw'}} fullWidth>File {num+1}
</TableCell>
```

However, the onclick command doesn't trigger when I click the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when your code runs "hi" will be displayed on render. You have to change the code to console on the callback.

```
onClick={()=>{console.log("test")}}
```